# Cannot find the fallback endpoint specified by route values: { page: /_Host, area: }

Tags: blazor

I use [This Project](https://github.com/Suchiman/BlazorDualMode) and created a project exactly like it, But receive

Cannot find the fallback endpoint specified by route values: { page: /_Host, area: }.

Error when I start the project, In the startup configure method I have:

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");               
            });
```

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

1. Make sure that you have `<base href="~/" />` declaration inside the `<head />` tag in your `_Host.cshtml` file.
2. Make sure to specify `services.Configure<RazorPagesOptions>(options => options.RootDirectory = "/Pages");` inside `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` method in `Startup.cs` file if you customised your `Pages` location.
3. Try to remove `endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();` and check if it interferes with your routing.
4. Try to place your `_Host.cshtml` file inside the `RootDirectory` of your pages.
5. Verify that you have `@page "/"` and `@namespace <MatchingYourRootPagesDir>` specified on the top of `_Host.cshtml` file.

Comment: I also commented out two sections in .csproj file that ignore _Host: <!--<ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="Pages\_host.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Pages\_Host.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>-->

Comment: **RE 2:** this can also be configured using the extension method like: `services.AddRazorPages(options => options.RootDirectory = "/YOUR_FOLDER");`

Comment: Option 2 solves my problem. Option 1 is not needed if you set the base href in layout cshtml file

Answer (score 26):

If you updating project SDK to .NET 6, you can add following property into your .csproj file

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <UseRazorSourceGenerator>false</UseRazorSourceGenerator>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Source: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/36535#issuecomment-919861308

Comment: Thanks! But this now seems to break hot reload (using `dotnet watch run`). I'm completely confused... The thing was working fine for 2 weeks, then just stopped (completely out of nowhere) until I added this fix, which now broke hot reload.

Comment: Not proper solution - it breaks hot reload

Comment: maybe this solution no longer have needed because has confirmed at this thread, https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/36535#issuecomment-924664575

Comment: I had to do this when creating a new project in .Net 7 also

Comment: I just installed a new .NET version on my computer and magically a perfectly working .NET 6 Blazor app started displaying the error above, your answer solves it instantly.

Comment: It's working on my end. Thanks

Comment: I had this come up after installing .NET 8.  Making this change worked.

Answer (score 8):

.NET6, in your csproj file make sure you use Web SDK.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```

Also, add this to your property group:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
     <UseRazorSourceGenerator>false</UseRazorSourceGenerator>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web"> this was the real rason

Answer (score 5):

After updating visual studio we get this issue.
Adding this in project(.csproj) file fixed my issue:  (from [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/36535#issuecomment-919861308))

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <UseRazorSourceGenerator>false</UseRazorSourceGenerator> //added this line.  
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with .NET 6 Blazor server project and the missing part was to set correctly the `ApplicationName` and then "Cannot find the fallback endpoint specified by route values: { page: /_Host, area: }" went away

```
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(
            new WebApplicationOptions()
            {
                ContentRootPath = @"..\Sources\MyProject",
                ApplicationName = "MyProject"
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem in Rider. As it appeared it was wrong MSBuild version:
File->Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Toolset and Build: "Use MSBuild version: " - for dotnet 6 select "17.0" or "Autodetected (17.0)" (I had 15.0).

Answer (score 1):

This solved the issue for me: I copied the file "_Host.cshtml" from another project and forgot to change "Build Action" (file properties) from "None" to "Content"

Answer (score 0):

I am using Mudblazor and what I did to fix this error was to open the project with the file `sln`.

Apparently after you cloned a project with Visual Studio, it will open the project as a folder, thus, you will have to select the file mentioned within the  project open it correctly.

**Note**: I am new to Visual Studio...

Answer (score 0):

I began receiving this error for no apparent reason after installing and uninstalling a NuGet package.
The solution was restarting my computer.
I suppose the temporary file structure got botched.
Here's hoping I help someone else avoid hours of headaches.