# Blazor - .Net Core 6 - InvalidOperationException: Cannot find the fallback endpoint specified by route values: { page: /_Host, area: }

Tags: blazor

I just changed my project to .Net 6. I now get the following error
**InvalidOperationException:** **Cannot find the fallback endpoint specified by route values: { page: /_Host, area: }.**

I have not made any other changes!

I have seen and read the following.
Which did not help. Any ideas?

[Cannot find the fallback endpoint specified by route values: { page: /_Host, area: }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58874883/cannot-find-the-fallback-endpoint-specified-by-route-values-page-host-are)

Comment: Tell us _exactly_ which template you used and which options you checked.  Also post the program class form the server project.

Comment: Hi. what are you asking for.. this is WebAssemby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you need to install VS2022 and compile in it. I have a Blazor serverside project. In vs2019 with the same error when launching or publishing, but in vs 2022 it is launched and laid out on the iis and works well.