# when i run my program it says: InvalidOperationException: Cannot find the fallback endpoint specified by route values: { page: /_Host, area: }

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

When i run my blazor program i get that error everytime. I have tested on 3 other devices where i dont get the error but i get it here everytime.

I found a question that is the same as mine but for .net 6 and none of the solutions seemed to work here is the other one: [Cannot find the fallback endpoint specified by route values: { page: /_Host, area: }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58874883/cannot-find-the-fallback-endpoint-specified-by-route-values-page-host-are)

I have no clue on what code to give or what else i can try but i saw the _host page was mentioned alot so here it is, if it helps.

```
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@namespace RecipeApp.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <base href="~/" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</head>
<body>
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        <environment include="Staging,Production">
            An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
        </environment>
        <environment include="Development">
            An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
        </environment>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```